# Highlight selected image in HorizantalListView in android and it will remain selected untill another image is not clicked

Tags: android, android-listview, horizontalscrollview

I am working with HorizantalListView but when i tapped on any element of list then i want to show it selected and it should remain selected until another image is not clicked how its possible please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a toggle button instead of an imageView. And then create a selector on the xml with the various images you wish on each corresponind state. (I'm not sure now if the same can be done with imageView that's why I told you to use toggle button).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/button_rested"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled"/>
</selector>
```

on the laybout

```
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@null" android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
     android:src="@drawable/button_selector"/>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but here i am using only one image view and filling it dynamically (read total count from xml).

Answer (score 1):

Heres how I did it - My images were coming from a cursorAdapter so

1.) In the adapter, wrote a function

```
/***
     * To change the colour of list item selected
     * 
     * @param position
     */
    public void setSelected(int position) {
        selectedPosition = position;
    }
```

2.) In BindView for the class inheriting the cursor adapter

```
// Change the background color
        if (x == selectedPosition) {
            holder.title.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
        }
```

If your images are fixed you can just use selectors in your xml layout

Comment: i tried similar but it works up to image tapped after tapping once we scroll then selection is gone

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with XML using selectors or, programmatically with **onItemClickListener(..)**

One incomplete example:

**item_selector.xml**

```
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />

<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
```

And, instead of ImageViews, rather use ImageButtons for this purpose.

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/icon"
android:layout_width="50px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/item_selector"/>
```